# Blazor - Visual Studio generates different pathes to dotnet.exe in web.config

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis, blazor, web-config

I have two machines. One is Windows 10, one Windows 11. On both I use the newest (up to date) version of Visual Studio 2022. On both I have the newest version of dotnet hosting bundle installed.

I am developing a Blazor only project in Visual Studio and run and debug it in IIS (not express).

On the Win10 machine Visual Studio generates the web.config with the following tag:
`<aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" ...`

On the Win11 machine on the other hand: `<aspNetCore processPath="..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" ...`
Everything else is exact the same in both web.configs.

While everything works fine on the Win10 machine, on the Win11 I get an 500.30 error from IIS in browser. Windows event log here states that dotnet could not be initialized. When I manually change the path in Win11 web.config to the same, absolute, path like it gets generated on the Win10 machine it works.
Even though technically the relative path should be correct.

Why is it generated differently and how can I fix it for my Win11 machine?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to deploy a simple ASP.NET Core MVC application. If it can run without 500 error, you may miss the `IIS Rewrite Module`.

If the simple ASP.NET Core MVC application cannot run normally, please check the application pool settings to see if it is `No Managed Code`.

If still not working, maybe we need further troubleshooting step by step.

Comment: ASP.Net Core Webservices dont have this problem. It is indeed only with pure Blazor applications.
If by ```IIS Rewrite Module``` you mean the ```URL Rewrite Module```, it is installed on both machines.
Application Pools on both are set to ```No managed code```

Comment: I found out, why the pathes are generated differently. On the Win10 machine the project folder is on drive D:
Therefore a relative path is not possible and the absolute path gets set. To verfify it I moved it to drive C: on the Win10 machine and indeed the same error 500.30 occurs.
So the problem remaining is, why does the relative path not work even thought it should be correct